# Dynamically get TinyMCE settings (to apply them to another init)

Tags: jquery, tinymce

How can I get TinyMCE [settings](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce/#init)?

I'd want to take them from the first editor and store in variable (first or last doesn't matter, as long as script in question doesn't rely on id to get settings). Then, when needed, use them with `tinyMCE.init` to initialize new editor.

i.e.

```
var mysettings = $(".tinymce").last().GETEDITORSETTINGS;
$(".button").click(function(){
   mysettings.selector = ".newtextarea";
   tinyMCE.init(mysettings);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two basic ways you can handle this...

**Option 1 - Grab the current settings**

`tinymce.activeEditor.settings` will get you an object that contains the settings for the current TinyMCE instance.  You can then manipulate this in whatever way you need to create a new init object for the new editor instance you want to instantiate.  (You can also use `tinymce.get().settings` to target a specific instance as opposed to the active editor).

**Option 2 - (Recommended) Use a default init and clone it each time you need it**

The other option (and the one I would recommend) is to create a "default" init object as a JavaScript variable on your page and then reference that later.  For example:

```
var default_init = {
    theme: "modern",
    plugins....,
    toolbar....
}
```

...then when you want to invoke a TinyMCE instance you can use that base object to make your init:

```
var first_init = jQuery.extend({}, default_init);
first_init.selector = ".first_textarea";
tinymce.init(first_init);

var second_init = jQuery.extend({}, default_init);
second_init.selector = ".second_textarea";
tinymce.init(second_init);
```

*(If you are not using jQuery you can write your own object cloning method instead of using `extend()` - search SO and you will find many examples.  You don't need a deep copy for a typical init so a shallow copy algorithm should suffice).*

Comment: Works great, thanks. On a side note - if anyone would have a problem re-initializing TinyMCE - use firebug to check the ID before init runs, it has to be a unique, valid ID. If you need to clean it just use `.removeAttr("id");` (if there's no ID then TinyMCE will generate one for you).

Answer (score 2):

You can as well, without jQuery do something like :

```
// get current settings
let settings = tinymce.activeEditor.settings;
// define what you need
settings.height=150;
// set new settings to the editor
tinymce.init(settings);
// re-add the editor in the vue
tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, mceu_7); 
// mceu_7 = editor ID
```

Comment: `tinymce.activeEditor.settings` is no longer available in TinyMCE6...